# How does a const member get set in C++ copy-swap idiom?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

A simple copy-swap setup. Not worried about move operators. `constmem` has  a `const` member named `x`. When using the copy-assignment operator it looks like `x` will be uninitialized but somehow it is copied. How does this happen?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class constmem
{
public:

  constmem(std::size_t xx) : x(xx) {
    c = new char[x];
  }
  constmem(const constmem& rhs)
   : x(rhs.x)
  {
    c = new char[x];
  }
  constmem& operator=(constmem rhs) {
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
  }
  ~constmem() { delete [] c; }

  const std::size_t x;
  char* c;

  void swap(constmem& rhs) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(c, rhs.c);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  constmem a(5);
  // output in parens
  std::cout << a.x << "(5) " << std::endl;
  constmem b(7);
  a = b;
  std::cout << a.x << "(5) " << std::endl;

  constmem c = a; // How does c.x wind up being the same as a.x??!
  std::cout << c.x << "(5) " << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note to future readers: `x` can't be assigned and as a result the `swap` function didn't swap `x` This could cause problems later when assigning `constmem`s of different sizes, for example  if `x` is used  to ensure the program doesn't overflow the buffer at `c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
constmem c = a;
```

does *not* call `operator=`.

This syntax is just another form of [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which actually calls the copy-constructor.

Comment: Ah! I know I knew that at some point but the I was surprised still when it happened.


I also found out right after posting this that leaving a const member uninitialized throws a compilation error, at least in GCC!!